# Include Doxygen syntax in LaTeX?

Tags: latex, doxygen

I want to write documetation for my current appliaction in LaTeX (about technologies i used and so on) and i wander if i could use section `\mainpage` of Doxygen in him, as a chapter " how to use " , for example.

```
/*! \mainpage My Personal Index Page
 *
 * \section intro_sec Introduction
 *
 * This is the introduction.
 *
 * \section install_sec Installation
 *
 * \subsection step1 Step 1: Opening the box
 *  
 * etc...
 */
```

is this possible? Or all i can do is to write this as effective code?

Answer (score 0):

you could build an latex output with doxygen and include the code in your documentation